# Executor instance is not getting created while running Spark app on Kubernetes ( Minikube)

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, minikube, nats.io, spark-operator

I'm running Java Spark app on Kubernetes (**minikube**) using [spark-on-k8s-operator](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spark-on-k8s-operat) , java code snippet below :

```
static void minIOReadTester2()
    {
         System.out.println("*************** Getting spark session ****************");
         SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("spark-with-nats-readMinIO")
                .config("fs.s3a.access.key", "minioadmin")
                .config("fs.s3a.secret.key", "minioadmin")
                .config("fs.s3a.endpoint", "http://minio-service.minio-dev:9000")
                .config("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "true")
                .config("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
                .config("fs.s3a.attempts.maximum", "1")
                .config("fs.s3a.connection.establish.timeout", "5000")
                .config("fs.s3a.connection.timeout", "10000")
                .getOrCreate();
         System.out.println("*************** Got spark session ****************");
         Dataset<Row> dftest = spark.read().load("s3a://testbucket/outputdelta");
         System.out.println("*** COUNT *** : "+dftest.count());
         dftest.show(20,false);
    }
```

Sparkapplication CRD yaml file :

```
apiVersion: sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: spark-app
  namespace: minio-dev
  labels:
    app: spark-app
spec:
  type: Java
  mode: cluster  # Deploy in cluster mode
  image: dockerhub/spark-minio:latest
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  mainClass: com.test.MinIOTester
  mainApplicationFile: local:///app/spark-learning-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  sparkVersion: 3.3.3
  deps:
    jars:
     - local:///app/libs/nats-spark-connector-balanced_2.12-1.1.4.jar
     - local:///app/libs/jnats-2.17.1.jar
  driver:
    cores: 1
    memory: 1024m
    serviceAccount: sparksvcnew
    labels:
      version: 3.3.3
  executor:
    cores: 1
    instances: 2
    memory: 1024m
    serviceAccount: sparksvcnew
    labels:
      version: 3.3.3
  imagePullSecrets:
  - dockerhub-secret
```

In the dependencies I'm using [nats-spark-connector](https://github.com/nats-io/nats-spark-connector/tree/main/load_balanced) related jars as I need to connect with NATS in the future. As per [spark-operator-quickGuide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/quick-start-guide.md) had followed all the steps and running the spark app. Driver pod starts successfully however executor pod is not getting created. I can see executor code is also running on the same driver pod and is giving result on the driver pod itself !
In the logs I can see below lines :

```
24/02/01 13:51:46 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host spark-app-driver
24/02/01 13:51:46 INFO Executor: Starting executor with user classpath (userClassPathFirst = false): ''
```

And also by running `kubectl get events -n minio-dev` I can see only driver was created and no executors got created.

```
7m41s       Normal    SparkApplicationSubmitted             sparkapplication/spark-app   SparkApplication spark-app was submitted successfully
7m34s       Normal    SparkDriverRunning                    sparkapplication/spark-app   Driver spark-app-driver is running
7m16s       Normal    SparkDriverCompleted                  sparkapplication/spark-app   Driver spark-app-driver completed
7m16s       Normal    SparkApplicationCompleted             sparkapplication/spark-app   SparkApplication spark-app completed
```

On Spark UI also I can see `spark.master    local[*]` which means it's not considering K8S as master. Any Idea from where it's overriding value of master to local because of which it might not be able to create executor pod and running executor code on driver pod itself?